# Freeze top row and scrolling contents only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Actual codes are generated by javascript and jquery but simply I created html code as below only for the testing.

```html
<head>

    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div style="height: 40px; overflow: hidden;">Title</div>
        <div style="overflow-x: auto; height: 100%;">
            <ul>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>f</li>
                <li>g</li>
                <li>h</li>
                <li>i</li>
                <li>j</li>
                <li>k</li>
                <li>l</li>
                <li>m</li>
                <li>n</li>
                <li>o</li>
                <li>p</li>
                <li>q</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>s</li>
                <li>t</li>
                <li>u</li>
                <li>v</li>
                <li>w</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>y</li>
                <li>z</li>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>f</li>
                <li>g</li>
                <li>h</li>
                <li>i</li>
                <li>j</li>
                <li>k</li>
                <li>l</li>
                <li>m</li>
                <li>n</li>
                <li>o</li>
                <li>p</li>
                <li>q</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>s</li>
                <li>t</li>
                <li>u</li>
                <li>v</li>
                <li>w</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>y</li>
                <li>z</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run above code in most of browsers, it's run as I expected.(I ran this in IE-11, Edge, and Chrome)
Browser's scroll is hided, Title div area is freezed and list area has a scroll.
But when I emulate this code with IE-11 with IE-7 rendering browser's scroll is shown again and whole page is scrolled including Title div area.
Does anyone give me a tip for resolving this?

Comment: are you saying you want to support ie7 like rendering? thats asking for a bad time...

Comment: Yes, but I just want to know why overflow property of div tag is not applied properly in IE-7.

Comment: maybe ie7 never supported that in the way you expect.

Comment: You may try `<body scroll="no">` but not sure if this works

Comment: I reproduced the issue. Maybe IE 7 is not compatible with that usage. IE 7 is so ancient that I can't find documentations about this issue. Besides, I'm in favor of Chaska's comment, it works in IE 7.

Comment: I've just found that there is some mistake in my sample code.
Overflow property of second div should set as auto. So that I expect first div area is freezed and second div is scrolled. I will dig this issue further. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that there's no difference after changing the value to `auto`. You could still use the workaround `scroll="no"`. The result is the same. You could also post your research results if you have find something new.